# An antiderivative of an odd function is even. Proof in general.

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-verification, even-and-odd-functions

We have:

- $\int f(x)dx=F(x)+C$,
- $f(x) = -f(-x)$ - odd function.

Proof that $F(x)$ - even function.

---

My suggetion (please, check it):

1. Since 
   $\int f(x)dx = F(x) + C$,

   $\int f(-x)dx = -F(-x) + C$.
2. Since
   $f(x)=-f(-x)$,

   $\int f(x)dx=-\int f(-x)dx$
3. Hence,

   $F(x) + C = F(-x) + C \Rightarrow F(x)=F(-x)$

---

The nuance is that those constants are not necessarily the same. I mean, I know that this statement is correct, but I cant find the justification of this C-issue.

Even more. If eberything above is true, can we use the same technique to prove the reverse statement, i.e. an antiderivative of an even function is odd?

Comment: Looks correct. It might be clearer to write the integral as $\int_0^x \ f(t) \ dt$ and then do your argument, since $\int_{0}^{-x} \ f(t) \ dt = -\int_{-x}^0 \ f(t) \ dt = C -F(-x)$.

Comment: No, the problem appears to be asking about indefinite integrals (hence the constant $C$).  I think step 1 of his proof is in need of justification, since no elementary property of indefinite integrals says that is true.

Comment: @KyleC I'm not sure that it will still be the same problem. I try to provide a proof for an indefinite integral.

Comment: $\int_a^x \ f(t) \ dt$ is by definition the indefinite integral. @MarkFischler, he has used change of variables with $u = -x$ to get step 1 (u-substitution)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea is correct, but can be streamlined.

You can prove that two differentiable functions are equal by proving that they have the same derivative and the same value at some point. Equivalently, that their difference is constant (derivative zero) and has value zero at some point.

Let $f$ be continuous over $\mathbb{R}$ and odd. Let $F$ be an antiderivative of $f$. Then we can consider $G(x)=F(x)-F(-x)$. Then, using the chain rule,
$$
G'(x)=F'(x)+F'(-x)=f(x)+f(-x)=f(x)-f(x)=0
$$
and $G(0)=F(0)-F(0)=0$.

Can you prove that an antiderivative of an even function $f$ is odd? Not in general. There is only *one* antiderivative of an even function that's odd, precisely the only antiderivative $F$ such that $F(0)=0$.

Comment: I'm confused because you wrote that G(x) = F(x) - F(-x), so how can G'(x) = F'(x) + F'(-x)? Where did the plus sign come from?

Comment: @kat From the chain rule.

Comment: I’m trying to think if this works in general, even for non-integrable functions, and your proof seems to do the trick! Why indeed did have to assume that f is continuous?

Comment: @Bcpicao Continuity can be relaxed to “having an antiderivative”

Answer (score 0):

Basically, in step $3$ you use the initial value for the odd function $f(-0)=-f(0)=0$:
$$f(-x)=-f(x) \iff \\
\int f(-x)dx = \int -f(x)dx \iff \\
-F(-x)+A=-F(x)+B \iff \\
\require{cancel}\cancel{-F(-0)}+A=\cancel{-F(0)}+B \iff \\
A=B.$$

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is odd,

$$F(x):=\int_0^x f(x)\,dx+C\implies
\\F(-x)=\int_0^{-x}f(x)\,dx+C=-\int_0^{x}f(-x)\,dx+C=F(x).$$

If $f$ is even,

$$F(x):=\int_0^x f(x)\,dx+C\implies F(0)=C$$ and in general $F$ is not odd.